# How to simplify multi search in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sometimes such a scene when we use where in `Laravel`, like this:

```
if (!empty($request->input('user_name'))) {
    $where[] = ['user_name', 'like', "%" . $request->input('user_name') . "%"];
}
if (!empty($request->input('group_id'))) {
    $where[] = ['group_id', $request->input('group_id') ];
}
if (!empty($request->input('email'))) {
    $where[] = ['email', 'like', "%" . $request->input('email') . "%"];
}

if (!empty($request->input('mobile'))) {
    $where[] = ['mobile', 'like', "%" . $request->input('mobile') . "%"];
}
$users = User::where($where)->get();
```

but its so ugly, but I just want use the this `User::search($request->only(['user_name', 'email', 'mobile']));`, maybe we have to design some rules for the key name of the input name and do you have some good idea for this condition? Thanks.

Comment: Komal, how this will help??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes):

```
public function scopeSearch($q, $inputs)
{
    $where = [];

    foreach ($inputs as $key => $data) {
        $where[] = [$key, 'like', "%".$data."%"];
    }

    return $q->where($where);
}
```

And then use it:

```
User::search($request->only(['user_name', 'email', 'mobile']))->get();
```

Comment: I would add `$data = trim($data); if ($data) { $where[] ... }`.

Comment: thanks, I know about the scope, and I have edit the question,because,maybe will appear the equal not like and have to judge whether it is empty,so..oO

Comment: Usually if it's empty, you'll not see it in the array. But if you see it in the array, just add something like `empty($data) ? : $where[] = .....`  About equals, just add some logic to the scope which is checking if it's equal or like.

Answer (score 1):

For the convenience of search, I slightly improved it like this:

```
//use style
User::search(['eq'=>$request->only(['is_messaged', 'is_mailed', 'status']), 'like' => $request->only(['user_name', 'mobile'])]);
//the implement method
public function scopeSearch($query, $conditions)
{
    $where = [];

    foreach ($conditions as $key => $condition) {
        if ($key == 'like') {
            foreach ($condition as $whereKey => $whereValue) {
                if ($whereValue == '') continue;
                $where[] = [$whereKey, 'like', $whereValue."%"];
            }
        }
        if ($key == 'eq') {
            foreach ($condition as $whereKey => $whereValue) {
                if ($whereValue == '') continue;
                $where[] = [$whereKey, $whereValue];
            }
        }
    }

    return $query->where($where);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it without loop as follows

$string = 'CASE WHEN '".$request->input('user_name')."' != '' THEN user_name like "%".'".$request->input('user_name')."'."%"
WHEN  $request->input('group_id') != '' THEN group_id = '".$request->input('group_id')."' 
CASE WHEN '".$request->input('email')."' != '' THEN email like "%".'".$request->input('email')."'."%"
CASE WHEN '".$request->input('mobile')."' != '' THEN mobile like "%".'".$request->input('mobile')."'."%"
 ';

$users = User::whereRaw($string)->get();